# How to add list items from strings.xml in Android

Tags: android, listview

in my app I am having a list view. I want to list out the items from my 
res/values/strings.xml file. How can the items can be shown from there?

In strings.xml file how to mention the list of items to be used in the list view?

Comment: are you loading a array of string ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use xml parser to get the data from xml file.Then you can use this data in your list view.